# How can I import a module.export to my main code since it doesnt act like a function and it doesnt return any variables?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have started a little side-project which is about developing a discord bot that will be able to remove a given role from a given user in a server. I have designed a module (remove_role.js) to function like this but since this is my first project I can't find a way to import it to the main code (index.js). Below is the code of the module.

```
module.exports = {
commands: ['removerole', 'delrole', 'deleterole'],
minArgs: 2,
expectedArgs: "<Target user's @> <The role name>",
permissions: 'ADMINISTRATOR',
callback: (message, arguments) => {
    const targetUser = message.mentions.users.first()
    if (!targetUser) {
        message.reply('Please specify someone to remove a role from.')
        return
    }

    arguments.shift()

    const roleName = arguments.join(' ')
    const { guild } = message

    const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => {
        return role.name === roleName
    })
    if (!role) {
        message.reply('There is no role with the name "${roleName}"')
        return
    }

    const member = guild.members.cache.get(targetUser.id)

    if (member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
        member.roles.remove(role)
        message.reply('That user no longer has the ${roleName} role')
    }
    else {
        message.reply('That user does not have the ${roleName} role')
    }
},
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have read a little bit about how [require()](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) work.

The exported value can really be anything, it does not need to be a function. When you do a require() on the file, the file gets executed and you get a reference to whatever was exported from that file.

In your example, you would at the top of your index.js do

```js
const remove_role = require("./remove_role.js")
// You now have the object exported in remove_role.js.
console.log(remove_role.permissions) // prints ADMINISTRATOR
```

Comment: I have already tried what you suggested but it doesn't work. I have used all three of commands in the server "!removerole", "!delrole", "deleterole"